# .NET Core AppSettings in web.config Question

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Currently I have a web application that uses Environment Variables stored in the launchSettings.json file.

In the launchSettings.json file, the variables are stored under the tags

```
"environmentVariables": {
    "CENTRAL_APPLICATION_SETTINGS": "cas",
    "COOKIEEXPIRYTIMEINMINUTES": "5",
}
```

When I deploy my app, it then reads from the web.config file.

I realized that in the web.config file I can also use these tags:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ConnectionInfo" value="server=(local);database=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
</appSettings>
```

However, where do I place them in Visual Studio? They can't be placed in launchSettings can they?

Comment: Just create web.config file in .net core project folder and add it to solution. In file properties set it to **Copy if newer** or **Copy always** and place all required settings directly in it. If you **really** need it. But most prefer usage is to place settings in appsettings.json file.

Comment: But at the moment, the launchsettings.json file is used in visual studio. How can I point it to use the web.config instead when I run it on my local environment?

Comment: Oh, I see, you need to use this settings from visual studio directly. If that i recommend you to migrate your settings into appsettings.json becuse this file 100% used by application from debugging and published service.